# XCode 4 Framework - Private objects

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to create "private objects" when creating a framework? (meaning, classes that won't be exported outside)

I have a problem that my frameworks uses the JSON library and when projects using my framework try to also include the JSON library they get a "symbol already defined" error.

Thanks!

- Yoav.

Comment: If it is the same JSON library, can't the projects that include your framework, just not Link the JSON framework?

Answer (score 1):

With Objective-C that's not really possible. There are some guidelines to prevent collision though, for example one should use prefixes for members that are to be 'hidden' for other people and member variables are often prefixed with a underscore as well (Apple reserves the right to use 2 underscores). Which JSON framework are you using? Perhaps consider SBJSON if you aren't using it already, it uses the prefix (SB) to prevent collision.

From Apple's documentation:

> Prefixes are an important part of names in programmatic interfaces. They differentiate functional areas of software. Usually this software comes packaged in a framework or (as is the case of Foundation and Application Kit) in closely related frameworks. Prefixes protect against collisions between symbols defined by third-party developers and those defined by Apple (as well as between symbols in Apple’s own frameworks).
>
> A prefix has a prescribed format. It consists of two or three uppercase letters and does not use underscores or “sub prefixes.” Here are some examples
>   NS: Foundation
>   NS: Application Kit
>   AB: Address Book
>   IB: Interface Builder
>
> Use prefixes when naming classes, protocols, functions, constants, and typedef structures. Do not use prefixes when naming methods; methods exist in a name space created by the class that defines them. Also, don’t use prefixes for naming the fields of a structure

If you want to stick with the JSON library you use, and the "namespace" is the cause of the issue, consider adding a prefix to your own classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use SBJSON, but so do the products that use my library, which causes the collision :) I will change the prefix in y framework.

Comment: The other products that you use have included SBJSON as part of the binary? If not (the other products include SBJSON in code form), then you can just delete either your own version or the one included in the other product.